# add subview over UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

First of, I am noob to Swift programming.

I am trying to show a custom view over a UITableView.

I am facing two major issues :

a) The subview does not appear correctly firstly. ref image below :

[image: Appreance on addSubview]

and after few moments actual view  is loaded :

[image: Actual View Appearance]

b) After the UITableView is scrolled, the view is not coming over the current top scroll position of UITableView
[image: After Table View is scrolled]

Following is the code to add subview :

```
let vaAdPopupViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdPopupWithCrossViewController") as! AdPopupWithCrossViewController
                            vaAdPopupViewController.adID = adID
                            vaAdPopupViewController.tableView = self.tableView
                            if let message = parseJSON["adv_text"] as? String{
                                vaAdPopupViewController.message = message
                            }


                            let navigationBarFrame: CGRect = (self.navigationController?.view.frame)!
                            let frameSize = CGRect(x: navigationBarFrame.minX, y: navigationBarFrame.minY, width: navigationBarFrame.width, height: (navigationBarFrame.height - (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)!))
                            vaAdPopupViewController.view.frame = frameSize
                            self.tableView.addSubview(vaAdPopupViewController.view)


                            vaAdPopupViewController.view.tag = 1000
                            self.addChildViewController(vaAdPopupViewController)
                            vaAdPopupViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

also in AdPopupWithCrossViewController :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Thank You.

Comment: Add the popup as a subview of the view controller's view instead of the tableview.

Comment: @dan : It's Table View Controller.

Comment: Do you *want* your "Popup View" to scroll with the table? Do you even want the user to interact with the table while this "Popup" is displayed? It looks more like a popup advertisement that you want the user to dismiss to get back to using the table view...

Comment: @DonMag : You got it right. No, I do not want the Popup View to scroll with table. No, I do not want the user to interact with Table while popup is displayed. Yes, that is the case. Advertisement Popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to either create a `Present Modally` Segue or use `present()` via code.

You've already created your `AdPopupWithCrossViewController`. Set its background color to be translucent. Then you can present it like this:

```
    let vaAdPopupViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdPopupWithCrossViewController") as! ModalOverTableViewController
    vaAdPopupViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.present(vaAdPopupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then, your little "X" button can remove the ad with:

```
    @IBAction func closeTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

You can try out the various options on `.modalPresentationStyle` and `.modalTransitionStyle`, as well as setting `animated` to true or false, to get the appearance / behavior you desire.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan says, you should add your popup as a subview of the view controller's view, not of the table view. A Table view's view hierarchy is private and you should not be trying to mess with it.

Note that you can't do this with a table view controller. This has always bugged me, but it's a fact: A `UITableViewController` manages a single table view and nothing else. If you want a more complex view hierarchy you need to embed your table view controller in another view controller. I do this with a container view and an embed segue, which is very easy.

If you do that then you can add your new view controller's content to the parent view controller's content view, not to the table view controller's view (or to the table view itself)

Comment: Ok. But what's the issue with the appearance ? From screen 1 to screen two. Why is the appearance getting changed after a bit automatically ? Why is screen 2 not appearing in the first place?

Comment: Because the view hierarchy of a table view is private and what you are doing is not supported, so the results are undefined.

Comment: tl;dr: Don't do that.